# No coredump file generated in configured directory sometimes

Tags: linux, ubuntu, coredump

I configured one of my Ubuntu1804 user to dump ,

```
 > ulimit  -a | grep core
 core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
 > cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
 /var/tmp/cores/core.%e.%p.%h.%t.%s
 > ls /var/tmp/cores/ -ld
 drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 36864 Mar 10 00:05 /var/tmp/cores/
```

I can get most of the core dumps of crashed process in /var/tmp/cores, but sometimes some crashed process caused by *SIGTERM* has no coredump file in the directory.

I checked the log of the process  missing process, the log said the aborting signal was SIGTERM.

So how came no dump file for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the default action in Linux as described in man 7 signal is to terminate without coredump.

```
Signal     Value     Action   Comment
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
SIGTERM      15       Term    Termination signal
```